# How to add comment

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I want to know how to add comment for a question asked by a user, i tried a lot but couldn't find a button or a textbox which allows to add comment below a question, how u people put a comment for a question?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [faq] - you will find answers to most of your [so] questions there.

Answer (score 4):

You need at least 50 reputation to leave comments on *other* people's questions. (You can always comment on answers to your *own* questions.)

More information is [here in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), and [here in the description of the commenting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).